# Is {U, CZ, S} universal for quantum computation, for appropriate single qubit unitary U?

Tags: quantum-gate, universal-gates

In the paper [arXiv:0205115](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0205115.pdf), Shi proves that the gateset $\{CX, U\}$ is computationally universal for quantum computation, where $U$ is a single qubit unitary such that $U^2$ does not preserve the computational basis (and $CX$ is the CNOT gate).

I am curious if there is any such known universality result for the gateset $\{ CZ, S, U \}$ where $U$ is similarly a single qubit unitary such that $U^2$ does not preserve the computational basis? Or perhaps the gateset $\{ CZ, T, U \}$?

Comment: You can rotate everything and say that $CZ,U$ will be universal if $U^2$ doesn't preserve some other basis